# Can I use 'dogtail (Python)' for automating GTK GUIs on windows

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, ui-automation

I know that we can use 'dogtail (Python)' for automating  GTK GUIs on linux.
but I want to use 'dogtail (Python)' for automating  **GTK GUIs on windows**.

Is it possible? as I did not get any help from internet for this.
Seems like either nobody has ever tried this or it is impossible to use 'dogtail(python)' for automating  GTK GUIs on **windows**.

Please help me know if anybody have tried it.

[gitlab.com/dogtail/dogtail](http://gitlab.com/dogtail/dogtail)

Comment: I'm afraid GTK doesn't support accessibility technologies on Windows. Please correct me if that's changed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think it runs on Windows. Also according to this page dogtail has been inactive since 2013. But if you scroll down to 'GUI Testing tool' you'll find plenty of alternatives.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy

Comment: *"...dogtail has been inactive since 2013"*. The latest release on GitLab was May this year.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Linux Desktop Testing Project - LDTP/cobra [https://github.com/ldtp/cobra](https://github.com/ldtp/cobra) is looks like a great solution for this.

Comment: But again LDTP uses sniff in dogtail or object identification, so we need to install dogtail in windows. we come back to the same question!!!!!!
Can we use/install dogtail in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

> GTK only supports accessibility on Linux; there is no support for macOS or Windows, which means applications written in GTK and ported to other platforms are not accessible to ATs there.

Source [GTK blog](https://blog.gtk.org/2020/02/17/gtk-hackfest-2020-roadmap-and-accessibility/). See [also](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/question-gtk3-and-gtk4-how-broken-is-accessibility-on-non-linux-platforms/5981/2).